# Create docx via python (page breaks, tables) - possible?

Tags: python, python-docx

I'm trying to create a .docx document via python, but both methods I've found lacks one of my needed features:

- Set background color of specific cells in a table (to green).
- Add page-breaks.

I have tried with:

- python-docx: As far as I can tell, I can't set the background color of specific cells in a table. I can however add page-breaks.
- py2docx: Support for coloring of cells, but I haven't found a method to add a page-break.

Is there a way to do both features in any of these modules? If not, is there another one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word documents are actually compressed rar files. I saved a .docx with a single page break in it, and then un-rar'd the .docx file. There are a lot of xml files in there, but I found the one containing the page break. In xml, it looks like:

```
<w:r>
    <w:br w:type="page"/>
</w:r>
```

So then I looked up py2docx's source code, and found that the classes it uses (Text, InlineText, Block, Table, etc) have an `xml` attribute and a `_get_xml` function.

py2docx's Break class looks like this:

```
class Break(Text):
    def __init__(self):
        self.xml = """<w:br/>"""

    def _get_xml(self):
        return self.xml
```

This is for regular newlines I believe. But what we need is a page break. So I made a similar class, like this:

```
from py2docx.elements.text import Text

class PageBreak(Text):
    def __init__(self):
        self.xml = """<w:r><w:br w:type="page"/></w:r>"""

    def _get_xml(self):
        return self.xml
```

With that declared, I can use it like any other py2docx class:

```
doc.append(Block(PageBreak()))
```

I used the PageBreak in a new .docx and exported it, and it worked as expected. I honestly haven't tried sticking it in every possible place that the py2docx library allows, but I'm confident it should work.

Comment: Works perfectly for my needs. Thanks a lot!